# "undefined" in the URL when transitioning to a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

From my controller I'm transitioning to a route like this:

```
    this.transitionToRoute("posts.dynamicfinder", App.Response.find(obj));
```

the route for this looks like this:

```
    this.route("dynamicfinder", { path: ':some_id' });
```

Everything works fine except that the URL shows "undefined".

My guess is that because of `:some_id`. I don't have anything to pass but my model (`Api.Response.find(obj)`). If I remove `:some_id` then I can't seem to pass my model along ...

How can I get rid of this "undefined"? I have to pass the model in my `transitionToRoute`.

Here is a jsbin for an example: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/41/ To recreate the issue, type "5" in text box and click submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create route with custom model to id implementation.

```
App.PostsDynamicfinderRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { 'some_id': 'dynamic' };
  }
});
```

Comment: hmmm that gets rid of the undefined but now the url does not change at all. I would have thought it would change to `/posts/dynamic` as it does or `/posts/mostSold` http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/65#/posts/